# How to get the original attached view in gesture recognizer in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

By the following code I attatched a button in a gesture recognizer:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress=[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addLongpressGesture:)];
[longPress setDelegate:self];
[BUTTON addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Here is my addLongpressGesture method:

```
- (void)addLongpressGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {

UIView *view = sender.view;

CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view.superview];

if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){ 

      // GESTURE STATE BEGAN

}
}
```

by this code `sender.view` I am getting the attached view as `UIView` But I want the view as it was attached (UIButton), how do I get the UIView as UIButton?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change this

```
UIView *view = sender.view;
```

to this

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)sender.view;
```

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender.view;
```

`UIButton` is a `UIView`. If you know that your gesture recognizer is attached to a button, this cast is safe.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView* yourView = yourGestureRecogniser.view;
```

Since each `gestureRecogniser` has only one `view` property, this explains why a gesture recogniser can be added to 1 view only.